# Dimension of $\operatorname{hom}_{\mathbb{k}}(\ell, W)$ over $l$ when $k\subset l$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb{k}, \ell$ be fields with $\mathbb{k} \subset \ell$. Recall that $\ell$ is a $\mathbb{k}$-vector space, and assume $\operatorname{dim}_{\mathbb{k}} \ell=d<\infty$.

Let $W$ be a $\mathbb{k}$-vector space of dimension $s$. Prove that $V=\operatorname{hom}_{\mathbb{k}}(\ell, W)$ is a $\ell$-vector space and calculate its dimension.

I was able to prove that V is also a vector space over $\ell$, but I don't know how to calculate the dimension, since since $\ell$ is an extension of $\mathbb{k}$, the dimension of $V$ will be smaller. But how smaller it would be I think depends on how the  $\ell$ scalars do the mapping of $W$ to $\ell$ itself. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $k \subset l$ be a field extension.

**Proposition:** If $V$ is an $l$-vector space, then $V$ is a $k$-vector space and $\dim_kV = \dim_lV \dim_kl$.

*Proof*: Define the scalar multiplication $k \times V \to V$ to be the restriction of the given scalar multiplication $l \times V \to V$.
This makes $V$ a $k$-vector space.
Next, it is easy to check that if $\{x_1,\dots,x_d\}$ is a $k$-basis for $l$ and $\{y_1,\dots,y_n\}$ is an $l$-basis for $V$, then $\{x_iy_j : 1 \leq i \leq d, 1 \leq j \leq n\}$ is a $k$-basis for $V$; hence, $$\dim_kV = nd = \dim_lV \dim_kl.$$

**Corollary:** If $V$ is an $l$-vector space, then $\dim_kl$ divides $\dim_kV$ and $\dim_lV = \dfrac{\dim_kV}{\dim_kl}$.

---

Thus, for $V = \text{Hom}_k(l,W)$, if you prove that the scalar multiplication $l \times V \to V$ that you found is the extension of the usual scalar multiplication $k \times V \to V$, then by this corollary we have that
$$
\dim_lV = \frac{\dim_kV}{\dim_kl} = \cdots
$$

Comment: you sure? Wouldn't l change the whole structure of V instead of just scaling the maps?

Comment: @cor1.1.29 I don't understand the question. What is the $l$-vector space structure of $V$ you found?

Comment: Scalar multiplication by $\ell$ in $V=\operatorname{hom}_{\mathbb{k}}(\ell, W)$ alters map operations, not just scaling, impacting $\ell$-vector space structure uniquely.

Comment: @cor1.1.29 I don't understand you, honestly. If $f \in \text{Hom}_k(l,W)$ and $a \in l$, how did you define $af$?

Comment: nvm I got it now, thanks!